# how to add scrollbar to all the bootstrap div in html?

Tags: html

I am using bootstrap classes for my view page. But I want to add a scrollbar to my div. It's not adding.

```
<div class="col-md-12 row" style="overflow-x: auto;">
    <div class="col-md-2">
         <img class="pointer micro_otpt" src="https://picsum.photos/id/877/200/300" alt="user">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
         <img class="pointer micro_otpt" src="https://picsum.photos/id/877/200/300" alt="user">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
         <img class="pointer micro_otpt" src="https://picsum.photos/id/877/200/300" alt="user">
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-2">
         <img class="pointer micro_otpt" src="https://picsum.photos/id/877/200/300" alt="user">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
         <img class="pointer micro_otpt" src="https://picsum.photos/id/877/200/300" alt="user">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
         <img class="pointer micro_otpt" src="https://picsum.photos/id/877/200/300" alt="user">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
         <img class="pointer micro_otpt" src="https://picsum.photos/id/877/200/300" alt="user">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Expected Result:-

I want a scroll bar which will be having my last div. As col-md-12 will contain 6 div but the 7th div should be hidden.

Current Result:-
7th div is coming in the second line. No scrollbar is getting added.

Comment: just put a `height` in the same `div` with `overflow-x:auto`

Comment: @Roy its not working

Comment: bootstrap version ?

Comment: @LaljiTadhani v4.1.0

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `Bootstrap 4`, change this

Change Class Name `col-md-12 row` to `d-flex`

```
<div class="d-flex" style="overflow-x: auto;">
    <div class="col-md-2">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/zkvu9o5r/5/

Answer (score 0):

Create a `CSS` file and include it at the top of the `HTML` file, and in the `CSS` file write the following code:

```
body > div {
    overflow-X: scroll;
}
```

Comment: im sorry i misread the question. It should be x instead of y. Also min-width property of N pixels to the divs because bootstrap could be using flex under the hood to make it impossible to overflow.

Comment: Id never use Bootstrap in a real world application because of performance, freedom and overall professional quality but if you dont have the time then it is ok to use it. Just know that Bootstrap is not a good tool for development, it is only good for testing and if you are serious about web design then you should learn proper CSS.